# SharePoint workbench not reflecting changes

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, gulp, workbench

I'm building a SharePoint SPFx react web app. I've been using `workbench` for the last few weeks and it's been great. However, today when I did `gulp serve` I noticed that my changes are no longer being reflected. However on the temp workbench it's working just fine.

So when I go on: https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/Example/_layouts/15/workbench.aspx#/ and select my webpart it's displaying like a cached version.

However when I go to: https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench.html#/ it works just fine every change I do is reflecting.

I've tried clearing my cache, closing and reopening a new browser, tried a different browser, running `npm clean` followed by `npm build` , also tried deleting `node_modules` and reinstalling. Nothing seems to fix it. And I'm not getting any errors when I build or run `gulp serve` any ideas?

Comment: I did some more testing, the SharePoint workbench looks like it's not connected. I can add the webpart but looks like it's just a cache  version? When I stop `gulp serve` I would usually get a pop-up message saying I need to run gulp serve for the web part to work but that doesn't happen anymore so seems it's just not connecting. I tried adding `"dev": "set NODE_NO_HTTP2=1&& gulp serve",` that didn't work either. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

When you are trying to run the webpart on the SharePoint site workbench then close the window of the local workbench(https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench.html#/) and then check if the changes are reflecting or not.

OR

run "gulp serve --nobrowser" and then append

`?debugManifestsFile=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4321%2Ftemp%2Fmanifests.js&loadSPFX=true`

to any page in the https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/Example/. This will allow to debug the webpart in the SharePoint page.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/debug-modern-pages